# auto completion not work in VS code and also disable spotlight command + space from my Mac also not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

auto completion not work in VS code and also disable spotlight 
command + space from my Mac also not work. I use flutter and dart language.and gain it not work with android studio also

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+P to show all commands search box, then write : "Intelli". you may see an option to restart the IntelliSense . Also try to update flutter and dart, it may solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for replay I don't see "Intelli" in commands search?

Comment: Yes it's work after add Intelli. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks Stephen for this answer Try Ctrl+Shift+P to show all commands search box, then write : "Intelli". you may see an option to restart the IntelliSense . Also try to update flutter and dart, it may solve the issue